# MongoDB advanced count query, depending of document's content

Tags: mongodb, count, mapreduce, nosql

I've got an issue with an advanced count query with MongoDB.

I'm tring to count object ***inside*** a document field, but only if a previous element matching a query exist and ***is older*** in the array.

Let me explain....

I have got a **container document**, lookin' like:

```
{
 "_id" : ...,
 [...]
 "objects" : [ ]
}
```

Inside the objects fields:
I've got **object document** lookin' like:

```
[
  {
    "_id" : ...,
    "name" : "foo",
    "properties" = [ ],
    "time" = 000000042
  }

  {
    "_id" : ...,
    "name" : "bar",
    "properties" = [ ],
    "time" = 000000424
  }

  {
    "_id" : ...,
    "name" : "baz",
    "properties" = [ ],
    "time" = 000004242
  }
```

For now I count how many **container documents** contain:
***count*** of container with object 1 (foo),
***count*** of container with object 1 and 2 (foo and bar),
***count*** of container with object 1, 2 and 3 (foo, bar, baz)

But now I want to count foo and bar only if *bar* is **older** than *foo* (using the time field)...
***count*** of container with object 1 (foo),
***count*** of container with object 1 and 2 (foo and bar), **AND** foo.time < bar.time
***count*** of container with object 1, 2 and 3 (foo, bar, baz) **AND** foo.time < bar.time < baz.time

The probleme is that the time field needs to change for each container.
With other words: How can I use dynamic query per document

here a sample of code:

```
foreach ($COUNTER[ARRAY_FIELDS_NAME_TO_COUNT] as $key => $value)
{
// Build the query (Name & properties)
$match[$key] = array('$elemMatch' => array('name' => $value['name']));
foreach ($value['properties'] as $propertyName => $propertyValue)
  $match[$key]['$elemMatch']["properties.$propertyName"] = $propertyValue;

// Time checking
if ($key > 0)
{
  //FIXME with a... dynamics query searching inside current doc??
  //           or   a special var set to the previous object matched...  or MapReduce..
}


// Make the query
$query = array('objects' => array('$all' => $match));

$result[$key]['count'] = $db->person->count($query);
}
```

I'm new in MongoDB, and I really don't know what could be the best practice for doing that efficiently!

Regards!

Comment: are you using 2.2?  and is the number of these conditions reasonably small?  is foo < bar and foo<bar<baz representative of actual query you have to make or are there a lot more conditions?

Comment: Hi, yes I'm using 2.2.0, I have to match about 5 or a bit more contained objects like foo and bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can do this with Aggregation Framework in the shell (javascript).

Note that I've split this up into multiple lines for readability, the actual query is the last line.  I've used foo bar and baz but of course you want to adjust to something more appropriate.

```
match = { "$match" : { "objects.name" : "foo" } };
unwind = { "$unwind" : "$objects" };
projectDates = {"$project" : {
        "_id" : 1,
        "objects" : 1,
        "fooDate" : {
            "$cond" : [
                {
                    "$eq" : [
                        "$objects.name",
                        "foo"
                    ]
                },
                "$objects.time",
                0
            ]
        },
        "barDate" : {
            "$cond" : [
                {
                    "$eq" : [
                        "$objects.name",
                        "bar"
                    ]
                },
                "$objects.time",
                0
            ]
        },
        "bazDate" : {
            "$cond" : [
                {
                    "$eq" : [
                        "$objects.name",
                        "baz"
                    ]
                },
                "$objects.time",
                0
            ]
        }
    }
};
group = {"$group" : {
        "_id" : "$_id",
        "objects" : {
            "$push" : "$objects"
        },
        "maxFooDate" : {
            "$max" : "$fooDate"
        },
        "maxBarDate" : {
            "$max" : "$barDate"
        },
        "maxBazDate" : {
            "$max" : "$bazDate"
        }
    }
};
projectCount = {"$project" : {
        "_id" : 1,
        "foos" : {
            "$add" : [
                1,
                0
            ]
        },
        "foosAndBars" : {
            "$cond" : [
                {
                    "$lt" : [
                        "$maxFooDate",
                        "$maxBarDate"
                    ]
                },
                1,
                0
            ]
        },
        "foosBarsAndBazs" : {
            "$cond" : [
                {
                    "$and" : [
                        {
                            "$lt" : [
                                "$maxBarDate",
                                "$maxBazDate"
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "$lt" : [
                                "$maxFooDate",
                                "$maxBarDate"
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                1,
                0
            ]
        }
    }
};
countFoos = {"$group" : {
        "_id" : "FoosBarsBazs",
        "Foos" : {
            "$sum" : "$foos"
        },
        "FBs" : {
            "$sum" : "$foosAndBars"
        },
        "FBBs" : {
            "$sum" : "$foosBarsAndBazs"
        }
    }
};


db.collection.aggregate([match, unwind, projectDates, projectCount, countFoos]).result
```

Comment: Thank you, but I've read that aggregation are limited to 20k elements... And I want to match only few objects names, I've got a lot of them... more than 20k. So I've done that with a MapReduce for now. thx for your help!

Comment: I'm not sure what the limit refers to - the result returned is limited to 16MB (max document size) - so if your returned result would be much bigger then definitely you can't use aggregation framework.  Map/reduce doesn't have the same limitation but it can be more complex to write/maintain... And it's definitely a lot slower.